# Is there a torque table for hex cap screws?

Tags: screws

I find that especially with smaller hex cap screws the hex drive is worn out or deformed long before I reach the maximum torque that the screw could theoretically handle.
For example: I've used M5 ISO 10642 (8.8 alloy steel) screws recently which can be fastened with about 6Nm (which - if I understood it correctly - is 90% of the screw's yield strength). I found that the hex drive was starting to get deformed at around 4 - 4.5Nm and I didn't dare to fasten it any tighter fearing I'd wear out the drive (which has happened in the past with M3 and M4 screws unfortunately).

Now I could use a different grade of steel, use a different type of head (the ISO 4762 for example have a larger drive for the same thread diameter) etc., but I was wondering if there's a table for hex drives that lists the maximum torque for each drive size similar to [Torx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torx#Sizing)?

Cheers!

Comment: These screws are purely for mechanical fastening purposes, correct?

Comment: There are many available online, e.g. http://www.federalscrewproducts.com/torque-chart.htm

Comment: @DrMoishePippik the table you've linked only lists torque depending on bolt size. My question is about torque depending on hex drive size (which I suspect is less that what the bolt can take, at least for common grades of steel like 8.8 or 10.9).

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes, purely for mechanical fastening purposes (I wouldn't know what to use screws for otherwise)

Comment: @ClaytonLouden screws used for electrical connections have different torque requirements

Comment: @ClaytonLouden, If the hex *head* (not drive) is being damaged then the wrench or socket is the wrong size (e.g. an "almost" fit using SAE for a metric head), or the beveled edge of the socket extends too far, rounding corners.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik So you're saying I can always use the torque the screw is rated for, the hex head will always withstand that, e.g. I can always use ~6Nm on an M5 ISO 10642 8.8 screw (assuming my coefficient of friction is in the right ballpark, of course grease etc. might change that)

Comment: Yes. It would be counterproductive for a manufacturer to put a head on a bolt that is not strong enough for the required torque.